# How many different perfect matchings does $K_{n,n}$ have?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

How many different perfect matchings does a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ have?

Here is my reasoning:

Initially, I have $2n$ choices for vertices. Then I can combine one of these vertices with $n$ choices for a matching vertex (since it must be with a vertex in the other partition).

Next I only have $2n-2$ choices for vertices, and $n-1$ choices for matching vertices. Thus, total number of possibilities $2n*n*(2n-2)*(n-1)...$. However, I have to eliminate any redundancy. Hence,

$$\frac{2n*n*(2n-2)*(n-1)...}{n! (2!)^n}=\frac{(2n)!!(n!)}{n!(2!)^n}=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2!)^n}.$$

$n!$ because we have $n$ matchings and $(2!)^n$ to remove the redundancy between each of the $n$ matchings.

Could anyone verify this is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you calculate that?

Comment: @Arthur I've updated my question. Please, see my reasoning.

Comment: @MarkBennet I've updated my question. Please, see my reasoning.

Comment: How many matchings for $K_{2,2}$ and $K_{3,3}$?  Do you see a pattern?  Your first formula is OK, though more complicated than it needs to be, but the last one has one exclamation point too many at the numerator.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I think the numerator is fine. It is supposed to be a double factorial.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cancel all those factors $2$ you get a simpler form of answer, which you can recover in a different way by numbering the vertices of one set of $n$, and simply choosing matched vertices from the other set in order.

So the proof is fine, but it isn't the simplest way to get the result.

Comment: is the simpler form just $n!$?

Comment: @JoshSmith Indeed